# org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect does not support resultsets via stored procedures

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jpa, database-cursor

I'm trying to call a database stored procedure (Oracle 10g) with JPA 2.1 (Hibernate 4.3.5). The procedure returns the results in an output cursor:

```
PROCEDURE GET_EMPLOYEE(
  P_ID_EMP  IN       VARCHAR2,
  P_CURSOR   OUT   TYPES.cursor_type
)
AS ...
```

Java code:

```
@NamedStoredProcedureQuery(name = "Employee.findById", 
    resultClasses = Employee.class, 
    procedureName = "GET_EMPLOYEE", 
    parameters = {
        @StoredProcedureParameter(mode = ParameterMode.IN, name = "P_ID_EMP", type = String.class),
        @StoredProcedureParameter(mode = ParameterMode.REF_CURSOR, name = "P_CURSOR", type = void.class) 
    }
)
```

Call:

```
StoredProcedureQuery query = em.createNamedStoredProcedureQuery("Employee.findById");
query.setParameter("P_ID_EMP", "ID00001");
List<Employee> employees = query.getResultList(); //exception launched here
```

This Exception is launched:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect does not support resultsets via stored procedures
    at org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect.registerResultSetOutParameter(Dialect.java:1612)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.cursor.internal.StandardRefCursorSupport.registerRefCursorParameter(StandardRefCursorSupport.java:94)
    at org.hibernate.procedure.internal.AbstractParameterRegistrationImpl.prepare(AbstractParameterRegistrationImpl.java:298)
    at org.hibernate.procedure.internal.ProcedureCallImpl.buildOutputs(ProcedureCallImpl.java:417)
    at org.hibernate.procedure.internal.ProcedureCallImpl.getOutputs(ProcedureCallImpl.java:378)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.StoredProcedureQueryImpl.outputs(StoredProcedureQueryImpl.java:251)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.StoredProcedureQueryImpl.getResultList(StoredProcedureQueryImpl.java:334)
```

The same code works great using Eclipselink 2.5.1 (but can't use it).

I know I can get a JDBC connection from the entitymanager and use the classic Resultset stuff to retrieve the results, but I would like to use JPA 2.1 - Hibernate.

Thank you.

Comment: Seems like you are not alone https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-9286

Comment: Does this answer your question? [java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect does not support resultsets via stored procedures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38592137/java-lang-unsupportedoperationexception-org-hibernate-dialect-oracle10gdialect)