# java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect does not support resultsets via stored procedures

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, stored-procedures, oracle11g

how to solve the following error I am using JPA 2.1 widfly Application Server 8.0 and Oracle 11g bd

java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect does not support resultsets via stored procedures

Deputy code:

```
        StoredProcedureQuery storedProcedureQuery=em.createStoredProcedureQuery("SIB_PQ_SENA.CREAR_VENTAS",Venta.class);
    storedProcedureQuery.registerStoredProcedureParameter("P_ID_EMPLEADO", Integer.class , ParameterMode.IN);
    storedProcedureQuery.registerStoredProcedureParameter("P_ID_CLIENTE", Integer.class, ParameterMode.IN);
    storedProcedureQuery.registerStoredProcedureParameter("P_ID_SUCURSAL", Integer.class, ParameterMode.IN);
    storedProcedureQuery.registerStoredProcedureParameter("CURSORRETURN", void.class, ParameterMode.REF_CURSOR);
    storedProcedureQuery.setParameter("P_ID_EMPLEADO", idEmpleado);
    storedProcedureQuery.setParameter("P_ID_CLIENTE", idCliente);
    storedProcedureQuery.setParameter("P_ID_SUCURSAL", idSucursal);
    storedProcedureQuery.execute();
```

Comment: Can you paste the whole Stack trace?

Comment: update to hibernate 5.x and use 12C dialect

Answer (score 1):

Wildfly 8 uses [Hibernate 4.3](https://sso.jboss.org/login?service=https%3A%2F%2Fdocs.jboss.org%2Fauthor%2Fdisplay%2FWFLY8%2FJPA%2BReference%2BGuide%3F_sscc%3Dt&gateway=true).

This issue was caused by [HHH-9286](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-9286) which got fixed in Hibernate 5.1.0 and 5.0.8.

You need to upgrade Hibernate to get it fixed. To prove it, you can run the examples from this [blog post](https://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-call-oracle-stored-procedures-and-functions-from-hibernate/). All the examples are on [GitHub](https://github.com/vladmihalcea/high-performance-java-persistence/tree/master/core/src/test/java/com/vladmihalcea/book/hpjp/hibernate/sp), so you can test against any Hibernate version you use.

Comment: as changing the hibernate 4.3 to 5.1 in 8.0 widfly

Comment: I don't understand. What's "as changing the" supposed to mean?

Comment: then it serves me right widlfy 8
I would have to happen to the version of wildfly 10 .

Comment: You can upgrade Hibernate version in Wildfly 8 too

Comment: asks how I can update the version 5.1 hibernate in wildfly 8 an example that I find nothing. thanks for your help

Comment: Have you tried [this](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY8/JPA+Reference+Guide?_sscc=t#JPAReferenceGuide-ReplacingthecurrentHibernate4.3.xjarswithanewerversion)?

Comment: and update the hibernate but when we display shows me the following error

Comment: org/jboss/as/jpa/hibernate5/HibernatePersistenceProviderAdaptor : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0

Comment: That's because Hibernate 5.2 requires Hava 1.8, and you're running on some older Java version. I suppose you did not read the migration guides.

Comment: thanks already achieved on the application deployment without any problem but when I open the page not found 404 error appears and you can not be

Comment: and displays well and shows panta but still shows the same error and use also with wildfly 10 and also shows this error: org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect does not support resultsets via stored procedures

Comment: it may be something of poom.xml help Vlad Mihalcea

Answer (score 0):

After struggling a lot with this issue we finally found a solution and it is simple.

Following is my pom.xml,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>codeshare</groupId>
    <artifactId>statement-service</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.8.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <docker.image.prefix>docker_img</docker.image.prefix>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-eureka</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-hystrix</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!--data access JPA-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.7.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--<dependency>-->
            <!--<groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>-->
            <!--<artifactId>hibernate-envers</artifactId>-->
            <!--<version>5.2.11.Final</version>-->
        <!--</dependency>-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.common</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.validator</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.7.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.14.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.10.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>


        <!--end-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
            <version>0.6.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
            <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc7</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>Dalston.SR1</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <finalName>statement-service</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>Application</mainClass>
                    <addResources>true</addResources>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.spotify</groupId>
                <artifactId>dockerfile-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.3.6</version>
                <configuration>
                    <repository>${docker.image.prefix}/${project.artifactId}</repository>
                    <buildArgs>
                        <JAR_FILE>target/${project.build.finalName}.jar</JAR_FILE>
                    </buildArgs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

and this has to be added to your property file and that's it
`spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect`
(* ':' should be replaced with '=' if you are using a application.property , i'm using application.yml)

Hope it helps someone.